Most efficient way to remove duplicate ids in union query in Snowflake
Imagine I have these tables:
table_1:
    id   col_1  col_2 
     1   val_1  val_10 
     2   val_2  val_20

table_2:
    id   col_1  col_2
     1   val_3  val_30 
     3   val_4  val_40

I want to do an union of table_1 and table_2, removing duplicate ids, and selecting the values of table_2 over table_1 when an id is present in both tables.
union_result:
          id  col_1  col_2
          1   val_3  val_30
          2   val_2  val_20
          3   val_4  val_40

Both tables are massive (billions of records). What is the most efficient way to achieve this?
Thanks!

What are the indexes? Please show the full table defintion

If that query is run frequently and  the tables are not frequently updated then you can try Auto clustering, before implementing it check if that is cost effective for you.

What are you doing with the result? As there are billions of records I am assuming this is not just a SELECT query? Do you know roughly what proportion of IDs exist in both tables?

I join NickW's question. If you only need the action specified in the question, you can only use table_1 left join table_2 on table_1.id=table_2.id or select ...table_2.col_1,col_2 where table2_id=table1_id. I think, there are no other options.

So it sounds like you want all rows from table_2 and only the rows in table_1 that don't have a match in table_2
select * from table_2
union all
select * from table_1 
where not exists
(select 1 from table_2
where t2.id = t1.id)

