How to consolidate two rows based on data source?
Using snowflake for this:
I have a query that produces a very simple table union from 5 difference data sources:
WITH personal_info_workday AS (
    SELECT
        'Workday' AS source,
        CAST(w.worker_code AS string) AS employee_id,
        w.business_site_summary_name AS office_location
    FROM
        prod_raw.workday_prod.worker w
),
personal_info_bamboo AS (
    SELECT
        'Bamboo' AS source,
        NULL AS employee_id,
        NULL AS office_location
    FROM    
        prod_raw.bamboohr.employee e
),
personal_info_adp AS (
    SELECT
        'ADP' AS source,
        CAST(w.id AS string) AS employee_id,
        NULL AS office_location
    FROM
        prod_raw.adp_workforce_now.worker w
),
personal_info_salesforce AS (
    SELECT
        'Salesforce' AS source,
        CAST(c.workday_id__c AS string) AS employee_id,
        c.office_location__c AS office_location
    FROM 
        prod_raw.salesforce_corp_hub.contact c
    WHERE
        c.full_time_part_time__c = 'Contractor'
),
personal_info_mihi AS (
    SELECT
        'Mihi' AS source,
        CAST(e.employee_number AS string) AS employee_id,
        NULL AS office_location
    FROM 
        prod_raw.mihi.employees e
)
SELECT * FROM personal_info_workday
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM personal_info_salesforce s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM personal_info_workday w
    WHERE s.employee_id = w.employee_id
)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM personal_info_bamboo
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM personal_info_adp
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM personal_info_mihi
ORDER BY employee_id asc

It produces this table:



SOURCE
EMPLOYEE_ID
Office Location




ADP
57
1


Salesforce
57
2


Workday
57
2


Bamboo
58
3


Salesforce
59
4


Mihi
1010013461
5



Anytime there's an instance of an employee number matching in the workday and salesforce [source] at the same time (ID 57), I want only the workday row returned, filter out the salesforce duplicate. Any other instance of the employee number showing (like with ADP also having id 57), just leave it be.
This is how I want the table to look:



SOURCE
EMPLOYEE_ID
Office Location




ADP
57
1


Workday
57
2


Bamboo
58
3


Salesforce
59
4


Mihi
1010013461
5



I tried utilizing this, but it wasn't consolidating correctly:
SELECT *
FROM personal_info_salesforce s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM personal_info_workday w
    WHERE s.employee_id = w.employee_id
)

Here's a query to show the union data for something like DB fiddle:
CREATE TABLE employee_office_location (
    source VARCHAR(50),
    employee_id VARCHAR(50),
    office_location INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (source, employee_id) -- Ensures each (source, employee_id) pair is unique
);
INSERT INTO employee_office_location (source, employee_id, office_location) VALUES
('ADP', '1', 1),
('Salesforce', '57', 2),
('Workday', '57', 2),
('Bamboo', '58', 3),
('Salesforce', '59', 4),
('Mihi', '1010013461', 5);

Any ideas?

This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78871429/most-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicate-ids-in-union-query-in-snowflake/78875203#78875203

@NidenK can you upvote the answer since you accepted it already


Step 1: Aggregate the sources in one list
Step 2: Build the logic checks based on the sources and list of sources
Step 3: Filter out the results that follow the logic from step 2

with main as (

SELECT 'ADP' AS source, '57' AS employee_id, 1 AS office_location
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Salesforce', '57', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Workday', '57', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bamboo', '58', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Salesforce', '59', 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mihi', '1010013461', 5
),

test as ( 
select *, list_agg(source) over(partition by employee_id) as list_of_sources 
from main 
),
logic as (
select *, 
if(list_of_sources like '%Salesforce%' and list_of_sources like '%Workday%', true,false) as is_list_salesforce_and_workday, 
if(list_of_sources like '%Salesforce%' and list_of_sources like '%Workday%' and source = 'Salesforce', true,false) as is_list_salesforce_and_workday_and_source_is_salesforce
 from test
)

select source, employee_id, office_location   from logic where  not is_list_salesforce_and_workday OR not is_list_salesforce_and_workday_and_source_is_salesforce
order by employee_id


